# Access parent scope variable in child controller template - Angular

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How would I access parent scope variable in child controller template?

I have child controller (time picker) and want to change the button text under child controller by parent controller. How would I modify the value of child template using parent controller?

Plunker code: `https://plnkr.co/edit/WVFVTF7wKsGTgOrBfADB?p=preview``enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

Child views have automatically access to $scope properties. Just access them as you normally would.

Modifying parent properties is slightly more "difficult". I would suggest using a setter to modify the property on parent. If you modify it as you normally would (by simply assigning a value), it will create a locally scoped copy with the new value instead of modifying the existing on the parent.

Do the following on your parent controller:

```
$scope.myValue = "foo";
$scope.changeMyValue = function (value) {
    $scope.myValue = value;
}
```

Then call the `changeMyValue` method from your child controller.

If you want to modify child properties, I would suggest events.

Do this in your parent controller to fire an event:

```
$scope.$broadcast('myEventName', myValue);
```

You can receive the event on your child controller this way:

```
$scope.$on('myEventName', (event, value) => handleEvent(value));
```